# BSOD after successful Win10 install to external SSD on Mac OS cause: WppRecorder.sys

Tags: windows-10, mac, virtualbox, bsod, external-drive

I don't know how to fix a BSOD I get booting for the first time into a newly installed Win 10 on my MacBook Air. I did a VirtualBox install to an external SSD (Samsung T5), actually installing it directly to the hard drive by tricking the installer into thinking the SSD was the primary OS X drive. The installation was successful even doing all the reboots during the install, but when finished and booting for the first time to the newly installed OS, Windows gives me a BSOD with error code: DRIVER UNLOADED WITHOUT CANCELLING OPERATION against WppRecorder.sys.

Further research revealed that this error happens due to Microsoft including a new version of the WppRecorder.sys driver in the October 2018 build that has a major bug when you are trying to run Windows from a media that is accessed through USB. The fix is to replace C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\WppRecorder.sys from your media with an earlier version, such as the one you can find from the April 2018 release.

I don't know the right way to replace the current driver. I was able to get an official April WppRecorder.sys driver and I went into the System32>Drivers folder on the external SSD (from my Mac Finder, which can read/write the NTFS with Paragon's sw installed,) and I renamed the October version to .old and copy-pasted the April version. I rebooted and the boot screen did not have the windows logo or the spinning dots, it was completely blank and just sat there.

I know that I can just try a new install using the April ISO, but before going through all that again, I wanted to know if there was a way to fix this on the successful install that I currently have. Did I replace the WppRecorder.sys the wrong way? Is it because the metadata of that file does not match the October install?

Answer (score 2):

I would boot the system into WinPE from a USB flash drive to replace WppRecorder.sys in Windows 10 1809 (October 2018 Update) with the version in 1803 (April 2018 Update).

The replacement needs to be done in two locations:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers

C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-wpprecorder_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17763.1_none_060210566a88f6b5
```